# Unable to upsert edited values

Tags: visualforce, apex, upsert

I have built a VF page with few checkboxes as columns. I'm able to inline edit, but cannot commit the changes to database. This is what I have tried so far...

```
public class UserController{
public list<wrapgroupwise> singlegroup= new List<wrapgroupwise>();
public List<wrapgroupwise> getStartHere(){
List<Subscription_Detail__c> tempUsers=[SELECT name, field1,field2,field3 from   Subscription_Detail__c];
for(Integer i=0; i<tempUsers.size() ; i++){
           singlegroup.add( new wrapgroupwise(tempUsers[i])); 
    }
return singlegroup ;
upsert(tempUsers);
} 
//wrapper class
 public class wrapgroupwise{
 public Subscription_Detail__c acc {get;set;}

 public wrapgroupwise(Subscription_Detail__c a){
     acc=a;

 } //end of wrapper class
 }
 }
```

In VF...

```
 <apex:page controller="UserController" title="Subscription Details"     showHeader="true">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:inlineEditSupport />
 <apex:pageBlock title="Subscription Details">

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!StartHere}" var="gp" title="Subscription Details">

 <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
     Test Account
 </apex:column>
```

{Columns for field1,field2,field3}

```
</apex:pageBlockTable>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="save" name="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Where am I going wrong to save the records? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "can't commit" in your first line?  If so, please edit.  It's too short an edit for me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your command button has no action property.  The param `value` is just the text displayed on the button; `name` is not a documented param for `apex:commandButton`.  A typical save button might look like this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
```

Note the use of merge-field syntax; you are specifying an action in the controller, which is your second problem.  You are not using a standard controller on your page, so there is no standard save method available; and you have not provided one in your custom controller.

Next, I see you are trying to `upsert tempUsers` in method `getStartHere()`, after the `return` statement.  That code isn't going to execute; a return statement returns control to the caller - meaning any code after the statement won't run.  Even if it did, you would be upserting in the method that provides data to the page, which executes before the user even sees the page.

Instead of trying to build all of this from scratch, consider using a Standard List Controller; they are provided by the system for all standard and custom objects.  You should check out the entire "Standard List Controllers" chapter in the VF Developer Guide, but [this page describes how to build an edit page using a standard list controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_edit_data.htm).  Note that in the demo code on that page, the command button is calling the `{!save}` action on the Standard List Controller.